# jquery ui tooltip for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, checkbox

I can't get the jquery ui tooltip to show for a checkbox...am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

```
<input name="item.AutoOpen" class="check-box" id="item_AutoOpen" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" data-val-required="The Auto Open field is required." data-val="true" value="true"/>

 <button class='m-btn blue' title="test" style='width: 200px;margin:4px;'>hello</button>
​
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("*").tooltip({ content: "Awesome title!" });     
    });
</script>
```

Works for the button but not the checkbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/123/

EDIT: wasn't working because of the lack of a title (which I had avoided adding because you cant add a title easily using EditorFor in ASP.Net MVC)...

Solution:

```
 $(':checked').attr('title', 'Auto Load').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add title attribute to the checkbox

Comment: thanks that does it...was trying to avoid doing that because of the limitation with EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC - ill try add the title using jquery before the call to tooltip.